# Ruby link_to error in second controller - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Looking for some help, I think I'm doing something silly but I can't work out what. I have created a `link_to` to remotely hit a controller action in ruby, so that I can mark an issue as 'resolved' (sending the issue `id` and `patient_id`).

This works when I am in the `show` view of my `PatientsController` but not the `new` view of my `NotesController`. I am designing a stripped-down patient record system for the humanitarian sector.

I don't understand why it works in one view but not the other?!

Happy to do this in a different way if this is not the appropriate way to do this. Let me know if anyone needs more information.

Thanks in advance

Ollie

---

**ERROR**

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Notes#new
>
> No route matches {:action=>"resolve", :controller=>"issues",
>   :issue_id=>"1", :patient_id=>2}

---

**ROUTES**

> resolve_issue GET    /issues/:id/resolve(.:format)
>   issues#resolve

---

**VIEW CODE IN PARTIAL**

This is the code throwing an error on some views.
This is embedded within an `.each` loop which I know works as it outputs on some views, and if I remove the following line then it outputs on all views.

```
<%= link_to "<span class='caption'>Resolve</span><i class='material-icons left'>check</i>".html_safe, 
    { :controller => "issues", :action => "resolve", :remote => true, :patient_id => issue.patient.id, :issue_id => issue.id, :message => "URL passed message" }, 
    :class => "btn waves-effect waves-light icon-to-text-btn red"  %>
```

---

**PATIENTS CONTROLLER CODE - WORKING**

```
def show

    session[:return_to] ||= request.referer 

    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    session[:patient_id] = params[:id]

    @obs = @patient.observations.last

    @pagy, @notes = pagy( Note.where(:patient_id => @patient.id).reverse_order, items: 10 )

    render layout: "no-card"


end
```

---

**NOTES CONTROLLER CODE - ERROR**

```
def new
    @note = Note.new
    @note.patient_id = params[:patient_id]
    @note.user_id = params[current_user.id]
    @note.note_time = Time.now
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    session[:patient_id] = params[:patient_id]
end
```

---

**ISSUE CONTROLLER CODE**

This works as expected.

```
def resolve

    @issue = Issue.find(params[:issue_id])  
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])

    if @issue.update_attributes(:resolved => Time.now, :resolved_by => current_user.id, :resolved_note => "Hard coded test message")
        flash[:success] = "Resolved " + @issue.title
    else
        flash[:error] = "Failed to resolve " + @issue.title
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :refresh  } # this will look for a file names create.js.erb in views/links directory
    end

end
```

---

**ROUTES FILE**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :allergies
  resources :prescriptions
  resources :issues

  get 'issues/:id/resolve' => 'issues#resolve', as: :resolve_issue

  get 'notes/:id/sign' => 'notes#sign', as: :sign_note
  get 'notes/:id/hide' => 'notes#hide', as: :hide_note

  get 'patients/:id/show' => 'patients#show', as: :show_patient

  resources :notes
  resources :observations
  resources :patients

end
```

Comment: Might be worth posting the contents of your `routes.rb` file

Comment: also I do not see where  are you using `:resolve` method? Please post your `issue controller`as well, cause so far what I understand from your code, your trying to run `resolve` method in the `issue` controller which does not exist

Answer (score 1):

so basically what you need in you `issueController`:

```rb
class IssueController < ApplicationController
  def resolve
    # do some staf here
  end
end
```

and in `routes.rb` you should have something like

```rb
get 'issues/:id/resolve', to: "issue#resolved", as: :resolve
```

and then you can create your link like:

```rb
link_to "Check", resolve_path
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm pretty sure that's not my issue, as the link is rendered in the Patient `show` view and works as expected (I have now added the code I have in the `IssueController`). The route is already present when I enter the command `rake routes`. For some reason the route isn't recognised within a view for the model `Notes`, in the `show` view.

Comment: please post you `route.rb` and controlles so I will be able to come up with better solution

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to this route:

```
get 'issues/:id/resolve' => 'issues#resolve', as: :resolve_issue
```

Here you have the :id parameter but in the `link_to` helper you have `:issue_id => issue.id`

So you should change your route to smth like this:

```
get '/issues/:issue_id/resolve/:patient_id => "issues#resolve", as: :resolve_issue
```

Btw it will be more elegant to change your `link_to` to this:

```
<%= link_to resolve_issue_path(issue, issue.patient, message: "URL passed message"), remote: true, class: "btn waves-effect waves-light icon-to-text-btn red" do %>
  <span class='caption'>Resolve</span><i class='material-icons left'>check</i>
<% end %>
```